# disable clicks and mouseevents in javascript for a flash embed/object tag

Tags: javascript, flash, events, click

I have a flash object on my page and I want to disable clicks on it using Javascript. I tried to use the following code:

```
document.getElementById('flash-obj').onclick = function(){return false;};
document.getElementById('flash-obj').onmouseup = function(){return false;};
document.getElementById('flash-obj').onmousedown = function(){return false;};
```

It doesn't work. Is there any other alternative? Any examples would be appreciated.

Cheers
Nyo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the only way to achieve what you want is using absolutely positioned  element on top of the flash-object. The same technic is used to prevent mouse events to fire in iframe instead of main document.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Although my described code works in some cases, it still doesn't work in all cases. The only (javascript only) way is with a transparent absolutely positioned div. Therefore, I accept your solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could use **ExternalInterface**, something like this:

In flash, register a callback:

```
if (ExternalInterface.available)
{
    flash.external.ExternalInterface.addCallback("myExternalMethod", myFunction);
}

function myFunction():void
{
    myObj.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, someFunction);
}
```

in JS, call the Flash method:

```
document.getElementById('flash-obj').myExternalMethod();
```

Comment: Yes, that is a correct solution, but only if I had access to the flash code. However, I don't and I was looking for a dirty only Javascript solution. Thanks for the answer anyway, your way is the correct way to go in any other situation.